# How to change the highlighted color of a UIButton?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I created a navigation button in my UINavigationController.
I set it to be highlighted when touched:

```
[someButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
```

Is there a way to change the highlighted color to something other than the default white?

Comment: Do you want to change background colour or text colour?

Comment: Replace the background color when highlighted...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try to Override the UIButton with the following Method.. and just change the backgroud color of button when its in highlighted state.

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];

    if (highlighted) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor Your Customcolor];
    }
    else{
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor Your DefaultColor];
    }   

}
```

Try it..hope it helps

Comment: This is good but I'd recommend also resetting the background color when the button is not highlighted.

Comment: Example: self.backgroundColor = highlighted ? [UIColor darkGrayColor] : [UIColor blueColor];

Answer (score 48):

You can use `setBackgroundImage:forState:` to set the background image for the button when highlighted.

ex:

As suggested by Tim in [their answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523348/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-uibutton-while-its-highlighted/14525049#14525049), you can create a`UIImage` from `UIColor`:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Then set image as button's background image when highlighted

`[button setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor blueColor]] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];`

Comment: Ya, this is really the only way to change the highlighted background colour without overriding the control.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14525049/1292441

Comment: It seems you copied it from @ClementPrem link... this question should be marked as duplicated but in worst case it wouldn't hurt to give credit to owner...

Answer (score 24):

In **Swift**:

```
import UIKit

class CustomUIButtonForUIToolbar: UIButton {

    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
        super.drawRect(rect)

        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        self.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
    }

    override var highlighted: Bool {
        didSet {

            if (highlighted) {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            }
            else {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: FYI none of that code should be in `drawRect`. `drawRect` is for drawing to a graphics context. I'd personally put those into `awakeFromNib` but `init?(coder:)` also works.

Answer (score 5):

I'll provide a **Swift** answer, which can be used without any customization, if you want the highlighted color to be a darkened version of the original background color. If you, on the other hand, want a completely different highlighted background color, you can supply that to the highlightedBackgroundColor property as a UIColor.

The following is the most efficient and straightforward way to implement such a functionality in Swift. It is also generic, meaning it can be used for lots of different buttons with different colors.

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit

class HighlightedColorButton: UIButton {

    // A new highlightedBackgroundColor, which shows on tap
    var highlightedBackgroundColor: UIColor?
    // A temporary background color property, which stores the original color while the button is highlighted
    var temporaryBackgroundColor: UIColor?


    // Darken a color
    func darkenColor(color: UIColor) -> UIColor {

        var red = CGFloat(), green = CGFloat(), blue = CGFloat(), alpha = CGFloat()

        color.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)

        red = max(red - 0.5, 0.0)
        green = max(green - 0.5, 0.0)
        blue = max(blue - 0.5, 0.0)

        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
    }


    // Set up a property observer for the highlighted property, so the color can be changed
    @objc override var highlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if highlighted {
                if temporaryBackgroundColor == nil {
                    if backgroundColor != nil {
                        if let highlightedColor = highlightedBackgroundColor {
                            temporaryBackgroundColor = backgroundColor
                            backgroundColor = highlightedColor
                        } else {
                            temporaryBackgroundColor = backgroundColor
                            backgroundColor = darkenColor(temporaryBackgroundColor!)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if let temporaryColor = temporaryBackgroundColor {
                    backgroundColor = temporaryColor
                    temporaryBackgroundColor = nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Treat the button as a normal UIButton, with the addition of the optional property highlightedBackgroundColor:

```
let highlightedColorButton = HighlightedColorButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as HighlightedColorButton
highlightedColorButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
highlightedColorButton.highlightedBackgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this statement to set the highlighted color of the UIButton:

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, if you want to use a image for highlighted state, you can do this with `UIButton`:

```
if enabled {
 //highlighted state
     enableMicrophone.setImage(UIImage(named: "mic_on"), forState: .Highlighted)
 } else {
 //normal state
     enableMicrophone.setImage(UIImage(named: "mic_off"), forState: .Normal)    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {

func imageWithAlphaComponent(alpha: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, 0)

    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let area = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)

    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1)
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -area.size.height)

    CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, CGBlendMode.Multiply)

    CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, alpha)

    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, area, self.CGImage)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
}
```

Write

```
button.setImage(image.imageWithAlphaComponent(0.65), forState: .Highlighted)
```

https://gist.github.com/yukitoto/e8aa420e20be7ab5d64b71e96ecd61f1

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting some success by using an old, old web trick.

I've created a couple of image assets in `images.xcassets`, PNG files, both 1px by 1px. One is the normal colour, the other is the background colour.

I'm going from pure black to pure white, so:

In the storyboard I select the button. In the 'Attributes inspector' (right-hand panel, 4th icon across) I change the type to 'custom', change the 'state config' to 'highlight', then 'background' to 'whitePixel' (or whatever you called it) and 'Text Color' to 'black color'.

Now I change the 'state config' to 'Default', the 'background' to 'blackPixel' (or whatever) and the 'Text Color' to 'white color'.

I guess you can use these pixels whenever you need to apply a colour when you only have access to images in the Storyboard editor.

This does increase the number of image assets, but reduces the required code hugely. Which pleases me.