# UIButton: set background color (NOT IMAGE) for selected-highlighted UI state

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, uibutton

I'm using Xcode 6.1.1

Is it possible to set the background colour in code for the selected/highlighted state for UIButton? - Not a background image!

I'm using ID's for colors (e.g. @"theme.brand.primary") that are linked to a json file i.e. .plist file

I've done it for `setTitleColor UIControlStateHighlighted` which works fine... example code:

```
[button setTitleColor:[config getColour:@"button.text.pressed-state"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

However I want the colour of the button to change not the title.

There is no option for `setBackgroundColor:forState:` ???

Does anyone know if theres a simple way to do this?

Comment: Not directly possible according to the docs. You'll need to set a `UIImage` (of a specific colour) for each state using `setBackgroundImage:forState:`.

Comment: You can subclass UIButton and override setHighlighted method. You can follow this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300766/how-to-change-the-highlighted-color-of-a-uibutton

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just check for highlighted?

```
if (myButton.highlighted) {        
    myButton setBackgroundColor.......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have open-sourced a class, [STAButton](https://github.com/Stunner/STAControls/blob/master/STAControls/STAControls/Button/STAButton.m), to fill this functionality hole. Available under the MIT license. Works for iOS 7+ (I have not tested with older iOS versions).